# Consuming web API by Progressive Web Application (PWA)

Tags: ajax, progressive-web-apps, fetch-api

As far I know we need a HTTPS connection to successfuly install and update a PWA.
Do I need to serve API over HTTPS for my PWA too? Is this possible to make POST request over HTTPS using Ajax or Fetch API? What are the limitations of PWA in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far I know we need a HTTPS connection to successfuly install and update a PWA.

Yes

> Do I need to serve API over HTTPS for my PWA too?

Yes, because requests from secure to non-secure resources are often blocked by the browser.

> Is this possible to make POST request over HTTPS using Ajax or Fetch API?

Yes. You just have to type a URL with `https` at the front instead of `http`.

> What are the limitations of PWA in this case?

None.

Comment: So PWA behaves like a normal website served with HTTPS certifice and the fact that all the data are cached on local drive means nothing?

Comment: The service worker (which might or might not cache "all the data") means nothing *limiting* (which is what you asked).

Comment: But if I use a normal offline website the is not possible to perform a HTTPS request to external API because the webiste is not actually on the web server. Is it still possibile to perform HTTPS requests to external API If a website will be cached?.

Comment: "But if I use a normal offline website the is not possible to perform a HTTPS request to external API because the webiste is not actually on the web server." — That's not true. You might have Same Origin Policy issues, but that has to do with the Origin of the site not having permission. Nothing to do with being a `file:` scheme URL or making a request to an `https:` scheme URL.

Comment: I didn't write anything about URI itself. Then, tell me how the message to external API will be certified? Normally from offline website you can't send request to HTTPS website. There is also not possible to send request from website served over HTTP to API served over HTTPS (even if you will have CORS headers  supported by server). Connection will be untrusted anyway. You don't have a public key (HTTPS offer asymetric encryption).

Comment: "I didn't write anything about URI itself." — I did, because that is what is relevant.

Comment: "Then, tell me how the message to external API will be certified? " — The same way as normal. (i.e. not at all unless some authentication system is added.). This is nothing to do with regular websites, websites using service workers, or websites loaded from the local file system. It is just how HTTPS works normally.

Comment: "Normally from offline website you can't send request to HTTPS website." — Still not true.

Comment: I just wonder how PWA behaves. Is it like a normal offline website or (even cached) is it working like a certified website accesed over HTTPS?

Comment: "Still not true". Technically it is possible but request won't be encrypted so the server will send you an error. Still not what I want.

Comment: "There is also not possible to send request from website served over HTTP to API served over HTTPS" — Still not true. Look, here is a screenshot of me fetching data from an HTTPS API to a page hosted on HTTP: https://i.imgur.com/F4pRm74.png

Comment: "Connection will be untrusted anyway. " — The connection will be completely trusted. The server won't have authenticated the client (unless you are using an HTTPS client site) but that's normal for HTTPS and why people use usernames and passwords to log into sites.

Comment: "Technically it is possible but request won't be encrypted so the server will send you an error. " - The request to the HTTPS site will be encrypted. That's the point of HTTPS. I demonstrated it wouldn't throw an error in the screenshot two comments ago.

Comment: Just tested. You're right. I wonder how the connection is encrypted. Or not encrypted? I was wrong. I am totally confused now.

Comment: The browser sees a URL with the HTTPS scheme, negotiates a TLS connection to the server, then opens an HTTP connection through the encrypted connection. Same as any other HTTPS request.

Comment: The connection will be encrypted. That is what the S in HTTPS means.

Comment: So using Fetch API connection will be always encrypted when browser ask server over HTTPS? You mean Fetch API provides mechanism to handle TLS connection and then use HTTP over it?

Comment: Any request a client sends over HTTPS will be encrypted. That is the point of HTTPS. It doesn't matter what API you use.

Comment: Awsome! But, as you said, the client should be a HTTPS client which provides TLS. There is not possible to encrypt data using only simple HTTP client (we need to handle TLS connection first). Fetch API has to provide both HTTP and TLS handling. Thank you for an enlightening explanation.